# How to calculate probability of an event for a given month in a multiple years period?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

It might seem a stupid question since I could not find anywhere a similar one, or maybe I'm asking something that defies laws of probability, but at least I'll know if this is the case.

Let's say that I have data regarding hotel bookings, and someone asks me: "What is the probability of at least 3 bookings being cancelled in the month of March?". Now, to answer that I would probably use a binomial distribution, however, to build one I first need the probability of a booking being cancelled in the month of March. How should I calculate it knowing that I have data from the past, let's say, three years? Should I just do a ratio of all the bookings cancelled in the month of March in the year 2018, 2019 and 2020 over the total bookings made in the same period? Or should I take the ratios of each month of each year and then do something with them?

Comment: If you have enough data, you could simply go back and look at all the past March bookings.  Or you could try to model the distribution...maybe use a Poisson process with the observed mean for March.  Other models are possible too, of course.

Comment: The point being:  there isn't one unique way to use data like this.  To build a model, you'll first have to sort out which variables matter.  Is March a typical month?  If so, then using data from the other months might make sense.  Is March an atypical month?  In that case, you better not rely on data from other months.  Math can help you build the model, but the core assumptions have to come out of the context.

Comment: @lulu I thought about the Poisson distribution distributed along all the March months of each year but then I realized that Poisson distributions requires each event of each sub-interval to have the same probability to happen, but this is impossible to be the case considering, for example, that in March 2018 we might have 4 cancellations out of 10 bookings, in 2019 7 out of 14 and so on...

Comment: I don't understand.  One simple model would be to say that the number of cancellations in March was a Poisson variable with mean $\lambda$, defined by the data.  Mathematically, there's nothing wrong with that.  From a modeling point of view, there might be lots of things wrong with that.  Most obvious, the data set might be too small to compute a mean reliably.  Or maybe there are  obvious external variables (e.g. "in 2018 we were remodeling so lots of people cancelled."  or "sometimes the weather in March is awful, so many people cancel.  Other years, March is beautiful so nobody cancels")

Comment: @lulu about the assumptions, yeah you're totally right, so let's say that yes, i noticed that March seems a typical month, but still, the probabilities are not EXACTLY the same for each year of course, so how should I infer a unique probability for March? This is why I started to think that maybe after all my question cannot be answered in probabilistic terms

Comment: Once again:  math can't tell you what assumptions to make.  Those have to arise from the context.  All math can do is to help you work out the consequences of whatever assumptions you make.

Comment: If you have lots and lots of data (which it sounds like you don't), one thing you can do is to test your model.  Use part of the data to calibrate whatever model you like, and then see how well the model predicts the rest of the data.  If it does a pretty good job, then your modellinng assumptions start to look better.  If it does a poor job, then you can be pretty sure you are wrong about one or more of your assumptions.

Comment: @lulu that sounds about right, thanks for the tip! About the Poisson distribution, how would you compute lambda? The number of cancellations over the total number of bookings _over the entire period_ (3 months/90 days)?

Comment: As I said, you have some choices.  You can just use the March data.  The problem with that is you don't have much of it.  So then you can fold in the data from months you think should be similar.  At least February and April, say.  Be careful, though, as you should at least adjust for the number of days in the month (March has about $10\%$ more days than February has, for example).

Comment: @lulu right, thank you very much for your considerations, they shed a brighter light on how to think about these things (especially the assumptions part).